# How to persist query parameters on state update in Next.js?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I don't know why Next updates the query parameters on state update. So a user receives a password reset email and there is a link something like `http://localhost:3000/resetPasswordid=f171ec4b5290648ad8b2ef59975bdd274065dfb3&role=client`. So in my component that have a state that tracks whether the new password and repeat new password match. If not, it will set the passwordsMatch state to be false. However, when the state gets updated, the query parameters get removed and I am not sure how to persist the query parameters as it contains crucial information for me to be able make call to the backend. Below is my component. The issue happens in handleResetPassword because it makes change to the state ('passwordsMatch'). Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
const ResetPassword = () => {
  const [isValidAndNotExpired, setIsValidAndNotExpired] = useState(false);
  const [newPassword, setNewPassword] = useState("");
  const [repeatNewPassword, setRepeatNewPassword] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [passwordsMatch, setPasswordsMatch] = useState(true);
  const [resetFetchSuccess, setResetFetchSuccess] = useState(false);
  const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

  const router = useRouter();
  const queryParams = router.query;

  useEffect(async ()=> {
    if(Object.keys(queryParams).length !== 0 && queryParams['id'] && queryParams['role']){
      const server_path = process.env.SERVER_ADDRESS;
      let fetchUrl = "";
      console.log(`Query params, id = ${queryParams['id']} & role = ${queryParams['role']}, query params -> ${queryParams}`);
      if(queryParams.id && queryParams.role){

          if(queryParams.role === 'client'){
            fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/external/client/isValidResetPasswordLink?id=${queryParams.id}`;
          }else if(queryParams.role === 'salesman'){
            fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/internal/salesman/isValidResetPasswordLink?id=${queryParams.id}`;
          } else if(queryParams.role === 'fieldWorker'){
            fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/internal/fieldWorker/isValidResetPasswordLink?id=${queryParams.id}`;
          }
          const res = await fetch(fetchUrl, {
            method: 'get',
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          });

          const response = await res.json();
          console.log("response ======", response)
          setIsValidAndNotExpired(response.isValid);
      }
    }
  }, [isValidAndNotExpired, queryParams['id'], queryParams['role']]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === "newPassword"){
      setNewPassword(e.target.value);
    }else if(e.target.id === "repeatNewPassword"){
      setRepeatNewPassword(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    if(e.target.id === "email"){
      setEmail(e.target.value);
    }
  }

  const doPasswordsMatch = () => {
    const match = newPassword === repeatNewPassword;
    if(!match){
      setPasswordsMatch(false);
    }else{
      setPasswordsMatch(true);
    }
    return match;
  }

  const handleResetPassword = async () => {
    const passwordsDoMatch = doPasswordsMatch();
    if(passwordsDoMatch === false){
      return;
    }
    setIsFetching(true);
    const server_path = process.env.SERVER_ADDRESS;
    let fetchUrl = "";
    if(queryParams.role === 'client'){
      fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/external/client/resetPassword`;
    }else if(queryParams.role === 'salesman'){
      fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/internal/salesman/resetPassword`;
    } else if(queryParams.role === 'fieldWorker'){
      fetchUrl = `${server_path}/api/v1/internal/fieldWorker/resetPassword`;
    }
    const bodyObj = {
      "newPassword": newPassword,
      "repeatNewPassword": repeatNewPassword,
      "email": email,
      "passwordResetLinkId": queryParams.id
    }
    console.log("Email is ", email)
    fetch(fetchUrl, {
      method: 'post',
      credentials: "include",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(bodyObj)
    }).then(res => {
      setIsFetching(false);
      if(res.status === 200){
        setResetFetchSuccess(true);
        let routeToPush = "";
        if(queryParams.role === 'client'){
          routeToPush = '/signin';
        }else if(queryParams.role === 'salesman'){
          routeToPush = '/internal/salesman/login';
        }else if(queryParams.role === 'fieldWorker'){
          routeToPush = '/internal/fieldWorker/login';
        }
        setTimeout(function(){
          window.localStorage.clear();
          router.push({pathname: routeToPush});
        }, 3000)
        return;
      }else{
        setResetFetchSuccess(false);
      }
    });
  }


  return (
    <>
      {queryParams.id && queryParams.role ? 
      <>
        {isValidAndNotExpired ? 
          <div className={ResetPasswordStyles.parent_container}>
            <div className={ResetPasswordStyles.logo}>
              <Image src={CompanyLogo} layout='fill' objectFit='contain'></Image>
            </div>
            <Form autoComplete='off' className={ResetPasswordStyles.form}>
            {!passwordsMatch ? <Alert variant="danger">Passwords do not match</Alert> : ""}
            {resetFetchSuccess ? <Alert variant="success">Password updated successfully. Redirecting ...</Alert> : ""}
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
              <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={handleEmailChange} type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
            </Form.Group>
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="newPassword">
              <Form.Label>New Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={handleChange} type="password" placeholder="Enter new password" />
            </Form.Group>     
            <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="repeatNewPassword">
              <Form.Label>Repeat New Password</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={handleChange} type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>
            {isFetching ? 
              <Button variant="primary" disabled>
                <Spinner
                  as="span"
                  animation="border"
                  size="sm"
                  role="status"
                  aria-hidden="true"
                />
              </Button> : 
              <Button variant="success" type="submit" onClick={handleResetPassword}>
                Submit
              </Button>
            }
          </Form> 
          </div> : "Password reset link is expired"
        }
      </> 
      : <h3>Something went wrong!</h3>}
    </>
  )
}

export default ResetPassword;
```

Answer (score 1):

So I found a hacky way to get pass the problem. Basically here is the update:

```
const handleResetPassword = async () => {
    const passwordsDoMatch = doPasswordsMatch();
    console.log("Passwords match ? ", passwordsDoMatch);
    if(passwordsDoMatch === false){
      router.push({pathname: '/resetPassword', query: {id: queryParams.id, role: queryParams.role}});
    }
...
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).